# Unable to update values from one table to another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, accounts

### Ledgers Table

```
ledger_id   ledger_name dep_id  dr_bal   cr_bal
   1          Purchase     2     NUll     NUll
```

### Transaction Table

```
trans_id    trans_date  ledger_id   ledger_name    amount   trans_type
1            3/2/2004      1        Purchase A/C    84500   dr
2            3/12/2004     6         Cash A/C       20000   cr
```

These are my tables, `Ledgers` and `Transactions`. 
I want to update `ledgers.dr_bal` from `transactions.amount`, 
based on `ledger_id` which is the `primary key` in `ledgers` table.

Want to copy the values from `transactions.amount` to `dr_bal` based on `trans_type ='dr'`

So far I have tried doing ,

```
UPDATE ledgers
SET dr_bal =(select sum(If(tbl_transactions.trans_type = 'dr' AND transactions.ledger_id = 1), amount,0) FROM transactions)
where ledgers.ledger_id =1;
```

But am unable to run the above query, as it throws an error at the `Where` clause at the end.

Have tried looking into various questions related to updating tables here. But am really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query!

```
UPDATE ledgers
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        SUM(amount) soa, ledger_id
    FROM
        tbl_transactions
    WHERE
        tbl_transactions.trans_type = 'dr'
            AND tbl_transactions.ledger_id = 1) t ON (ledgers.ledger_id = t.ledger_id) 
SET 
    ledgers.dr_bal = coalesce(t.soa, 0);
```

If you would like to update all ledgers with the transactions amount, remove the condition of `tbl_transactions.ledger_id = 1` and introduce `GROUP BY tbl_transactions.ledger_id` in the sub-query.

Comment: Thanks a lot James Jithin, it worked perfectly fine, got the desired result.

Comment: However could you please  let me know about the terms used above such as "soa" and  "coalesce" ??  As this is very new to me.

Comment: `soa` is the alias name for the column `sum(amount)` and `coalesce` is a function which will return the first non-null value from the provided arguments. Ref#  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: Thanks James Jithin, I learnt something new, thanks for the information :)

Comment: However as am new to stack exchange, am unable to vote your answer as right.

Comment: @shiva86, no probs! Glad that the solution was right. Happy coding!